# Concatenation strings and group by IDs in Dbeaver

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have this table and all I want to do is a simple concatenation of the name grouping by the id.

```
id     manager
1      tim
1      anna
2      clara
```

My desired table:

```
id     manager
1      tim, anna
2      clara
```

I have tried with `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `LISTAGG ()` but I received the following error for both methods

```
ERROR: function group_concat(character varying, unknown) does not exist
```

I also tried with this but it does not work either because it said manager has to appear in the aggregate function.

```
SELECT id, CONCAT( manager, ', ') AS manager
FROM table 
GROUP BY 1
```

I'm using DBeaver 7.3.5. Any lead on which function I can use here would be really appreciate I researched but did not find anything I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message suggests that you are using Postgres or a Postgres-derived database.  That suggests `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT id, STRING_AGG( manager, ', ') AS manager
FROM table 
GROUP BY 1
```